# PHP display data from MySQL using GET

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to look up user's username using `$_GET` but not actually seing the result of the query. Here's the code:

```
<?php
$host     = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "toor"; // :)
$database = "db";

$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if(!$link){
    exit('Could not connect to database: '. mysql_error());
}

$email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET["e"])));

$query = "SELECT username FROM cc_card WHERE email = '$email'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    $user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $user['username'];
} else {
    echo "Something's wrong";
}
```

it's only returnung "Something's wrong". I wanted it to display the `username` field of the `cc_card` table where email = `email`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting *"Something's wrong"* from the posted code it means nowhere in the cc_card table does the email column match the email value you specify in your query.

You need to verify that the contents of your sanitized `$email` variable do, *in fact*, exist somewhere in the table. Try:

```
} else {
  echo "Something's wrong";
  var_dump($email);
}
```

To see the contents of the sanitized `$email` variable and manually query the database from the shell (or phpmyadmin or whatever) to find whether the value you're specifying exists or not. I'm betting it doesn't exist.

Comment: Oops, forgot to select the *database* :P Thanks!

Comment: I didn't even look to see if you were actually connected to a database :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd better add the error check after the query.

```
if (!$result) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

If no error, then it means there is no matched email in your database.